# Experess.js + angularjs separate routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, url-routing

I have a issue trying to set up an express + angular app.

I can load the assets files into it.

I will post here my code from the express and the html file. As far as I see Express is returning only the index.html file and nothing else, making all the routes return that file.

Here is the express code:

```
//server.js

// set up ========================
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    morgan = require('morgan'),
    path   = require('path'),
    app    = express(),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    jwt    = require('jsonwebtoken'), // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
    config = require('./config'), // get our config file
    User   = require('./model/users'), //get our mongo model
    routes = require('./middleware/routes'); 

// configuration =================
//var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.use(express.static('/client'));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));          
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                    
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/json' }));
mongoose.connect(config.database);
app.set('superPin', config.secret);
// start server =================
//
app.listen(8080);
console.log('App strated and is listening on the port 8080');
//
app.get('/checkServer', function(request,response){
    response.send('Works fine. Server started at default get routing to check if server runns.');
});
//
app.get('*',function(request,response){
    response.sendFile(path.resolve('../client/view/index.html'));
});
//
//exports = module.exports = app;
```

and here is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My </title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="pmt">
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script src="client/assets/vendor/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="client/assets/vendor/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="client/assets/vendor/angular-message/angular-message.min.js"></script>
    <script src="client/assets/vendor/angular-touch/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="client/assets/vendor/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="client/assets/vendor/angular-touch/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="client/assets/vendor/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="client/controller/routes.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I will add now a print screen from my folder structure:
[image: folder_tree_of_the_App]

and here is a link to the repo: https://bitbucket.org/cojok/pmt/

I saw the other related posts, but I can't manage to find what I am doing wrong.

I am getting this error in the browser [image]

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? Do you want server side routing or do you want angular routing?

Comment: can't get what is the wrong you are doing and you need help with?

Comment: I am trying to make the angular routing, but I can't load the files that I need. I always get this stupid error,Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < routes.js:1 ,and routes.js in the browser is a html file, because of express rendering only index.html. I don't know what I am doing wrong in express. I am trying to learn it and I got this funny error. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem is you can't figure out how to link files in views or how to set file routes on directory, so here you can do this as
Add directories like

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'scripts')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'Content')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'Angular')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'Views/Main')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'Views/Authentication')));
```

As content, angular and scripts are root directories and refer jquery files as

```
<script src="angular-resource.js"></script> //in angular folder on root
<script src="angular-ui-router.js"></script> //in script folder on root
<script src="/Controllers/MainController.js"></script> // in angular folder with child directories
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out my mistake or this could be only a fix. But actually changing this

```
 app.use(express.static('/client'));
 app.get('*',function(request,response){
    response.sendFile(path.resolve('../client/view/index.html'));
});
```

to this

```
 app.use('/client',express.static('../client/'));
 app.get('/',function(request,response){
    response.sendFile(path.resolve('../client/view/index.html'));
});
```

solved my issue.

Thnx